# Get view of a client in perforce through command line

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

We can know the information about a client using

```
p4 client -o *clientname*
```

but it gives a lot of information. Is there any way to get only the view of the client using command line?

Comment: I generally use 'grep'. Since the view comes at the end, it's usually easy to find. If the client is very large and complex, I redirect 'p4 client -o' to a  temp file, and look at the output with my text editor.

Answer (score 4):

You can use p4's `-z tag` option to get annotated output useful for scripting.  From there, you can extract the lines that start with `... View` using `grep` and `cut`:

`p4 -z tag client -o | grep -E '^[.]{3} View' | cut -d ' ' -f 3-`

(And if you're using Windows, you can obtain `grep` and `cut` implementations from [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).)